# Place an image element on top of a canvas

Tags: javascript, image

I would like to place the picture of the hand on my black canvas next to the face. Is this possible to do? Is there a way to determine the position of the picture?

Here's my code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="hand.jpg"></script>

<img src="hand.jpg" id="y" />
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1600" height="1200"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas;
  var canvasContext;

  window.onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';

    canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //Draws a circle
    canvasContext.beginPath();
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    canvasContext.arc(800, 400, 400, 400, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    canvasContext.fill();
    //draws head
    canvasContext.beginPath();
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';
    canvasContext.arc(600, 200, 100, 100, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    canvasContext.fill();
    //draws eye1
    canvasContext.beginPath();
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';
    canvasContext.arc(1000, 200, 100, 100, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    canvasContext.fill();
    //draws eye2
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
    canvasContext.fillRect(580, 175, 50, 50);
    //draws pupil1
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
    canvasContext.fillRect(980, 175, 50, 50);
    //draws pupil2
    canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
    canvasContext.fillRect(650, 550, 300, 6.5);
    //draws mouth

    function changingImg() {
      document.getElementById("y").src = "hand.jpg"
    }
  }
</script>
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Your image needs to be in an image tag, not a script tag: `<img src="hand.jpg" id="y" />`

Comment: @symlink - I know this is a simple question, but why did you answer in the comment and not as an answer?

Comment: @symlink Any way to overlap my code in javascript and the image? I would also like to know if I could resize the picture and link that to a variable. BTW that worked and I honestly cant thank you enough

Comment: @AndrewShepherd because I'm not positive I'm understanding OP's question correctly or answering it fully

Comment: @ggorlen I'm sorry man, I didn't know how to structure it. Thats my bad

Comment: This seems like a simple typo, you used `<script>` when you meant `<img>`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit--only problem is that it's a bit unclear as to where you want the image to show up. Can you edit once more to describe exactly what you want the output to be? Also, "attach a variable to the size of the picture" is a bit unclear--you want a way to scale the size of the image from JS? Generally, it's best to ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `<script type="text/javascript" src="hand.jpg"></script>` was a small mistake as it should be `<script type="text/javascript" src="someFile.js"></script>`. But if you were to make a JS file and link to it like that you would probably want to remove the plain `<script>` tag below.

Moving on, if you wanted to change the size of the image you can simply change the `.width` and `.height` property of the element variable.

For example:

```js
var image = document.getElementById('y');

image.width = 1920; // Sets image's width to 1920
image.height = 1080; // Set's image's height to 1080
```

If you wanted to read the width and height values you can do so like this:

```js
var image = document.getElementById('y');
var imageWidth = image.width; // Image's width
var imageHeight = image.height; // Image's height
```

Comment: When I remove the <script> tag, the rest of my code breaks. How do I fix this?

Comment: @AbsoluteNoob Did you create a folder with a name that correlates with what is within the `<script type="text/javascript" src="fileName.js"></script>`? Also, the file needs to be a JavaScript file which means it needs a `.js` file extension.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for the stuff you helped me with. Everything is working now

Comment: @AbsoluteNoob Anytime :)